# ERROR at line 10: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a proceure on oracle pl/sql, but i'm getting error.

My procedure's code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_LISTA_CLI (cpf IN VARCHAR2, p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  checkCpf NUMBER; 
BEGIN   

    SELECT COUNT(CPF_CLIENTE) INTO checkCpf FROM CLIENTE WHERE CPF_CLIENTE = cpf;

    IF (checkCpf > 0) THEN
      open p_rc
       for
        select 
            com.data_compra,
            lst.qde_produto, 
            prd.nome_produto, 
            prd.valor_produto * lst.qde_produto
        from cliente cli 
            inner join compra com on cli.cod_cliente = com.cod_cliente 
            inner join lista_produto lst on com.cod_compra = lst.cod_compra
            inner join produto prd on lst.cod_produto = prd.cod_produto
        WHERE cli.cpf_cliente = cpf
        order by com.data_compra asc;
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999,'ERRO! Cpf não cadastrado!', FALSE);
    END IF;
END;
```

The procedure is created with sucess, no errors.

But i got the error after calling it - CALL PR_LISTA_CLI(111111111);

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

How to fix it, pleasse?

Thank you!!!

Comment: select in the IF is wrong. You cannot just execute select inside a procedure. What do you want to do with this select?

Comment: You get the ORA-00911 error when creating the procedure?  Or when calling the procedure?  What is the line number of the error?

Comment: @Justin Cave i got the error after calling the procedure. The creation is ok, with no errors. Tk for ur help xD

Comment: @user3790692 - Then the issue is with the calling code.  What front end are you using to execute your procedure?  `call` isn't SQL*Plus syntax so I'm guessing that you're using some sort of Java/ C#/ Python/ etc. front end.  Some of those front-ends don't want the trailing semicolon which I'm guessing is the source of your error.  You're also not passing in the variable for the OUT parameter in the example you just posted.  Are you certain that's the proper way in your framework to call a procedure that has an OUT parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR?

Comment: @Justin Cave I'm using the Oracle Application Express - https://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html - and i test another procedure with DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line to show the results, but i got the same ora-00911 error =( if i use only a select query, the output is ok, but i cant use it with the procedure =(

Comment: @user3790692 - If you're calling the procedure in APEX, remove the `CALL`, it's not valid syntax.  You'll also need to declare a local `SYS_REFCURSOR` variable and pass that in to the procedure as well as implementing something in the caller to do something with the `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  You may need to wrap that in a pipelined table function to be able to use it if you're trying to build an APEX report (https://community.oracle.com/thread/904238?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 2):

Your compilation error is at line 10 which is where you are doing your `SELECT`.  Unless you are using 12.1 or later and hoping to use the new [implicit statement results](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1.php) functionality, you cannot have a `SELECT` statement in a PL/SQL block unless there is something to fetch the results into (e.g. a `[BULK COLLECT] INTO` clause) or you are using the `SELECT` statement to open a cursor.  Assuming that your query returns multiple rows and that your intention is to return a cursor to the caller, you could do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_LISTA_CLI (cpf IN VARCHAR2, p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  vEXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
  checkCpf NUMBER; 
BEGIN   

    SELECT COUNT(CPF_CLIENTE) INTO checkCpf FROM CLIENTE WHERE CPF_CLIENTE = cpf;

    IF (checkCpf > 0) THEN
      open p_rc
       for
        select 
            com.data_compra,
            lst.qde_produto, 
            prd.nome_produto, 
            prd.valor_produto * lst.qde_produto
        from cliente cli 
            inner join compra com on cli.cod_cliente = com.cod_cliente 
            inner join lista_produto lst on com.cod_compra = lst.cod_compra
            inner join produto prd on lst.cod_produto = prd.cod_produto
        WHERE cli.cpf_cliente = cpf
        order by com.data_compra asc
    ELSE
        RAISE vEXCEPTION;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN vEXCEPTION THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999,'ERRO! Cpf não cadastrado!', FALSE);
END;
```

Now, if that's what you're doing

- It would make more sense to create a function that returns a `sys_refcursor` since you're not modifying any database state.
- The exception that you've defined doesn't appear to be useful.  You're raising an exception and then catching that same exception only to throw a different exception.  Cut out the middle man, remove the exception handler and the `vException` variable and just call `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` in your `ELSE` clause (assuming it really makes sense to throw an exception in that case in the first place).

Comment: hum... I use your code, the same way you put it here, but i got errors yet =( Error at line 12: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


1. CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_LISTA_CLI (cpf IN VARCHAR2, p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
2. IS
3.   vEXCEPTION EXCEPTION;

Comment: @user3790692 - On second look, you are also missing the semicolon after your SELECT statement.

Comment: hum... Yes i can create a proceddure now, but when i use: CALL PR_LISTA_CLI(111111111); i got error: ORA-00911: invalid character =( If i use only the query is ok, but i would like to use it in the procedure... Some idea on how to fix it, please?

Comment: @user3790692 - Your procedure has two arguments.  You'd generally need to pass in a variable for your OUT parameter unless your framework happens to do that automatically.

Comment: my output is the p_rc , isn't it? I want the procedure to execute the query with value of cpf var choosen by user.

Comment: @user3790692 - An out parameter is different from a return value (one reason that using a procedure here rather than a function is potentially an issue).  The procedure doesn't execute the query.  It opens a cursor.  The caller would need to declare a SYS_REFCURSOR variable, pass that in to the procedure, then implement code to fetch from the cursor and do something with the results.